# Disable every keyboard function With javascript

Tags: javascript

How can i disable the whole keyboard and return an alert using javascript?
So if a person presses any button on a keyboard it will alert them a message specified by the creator

Comment: You can't, for example of `Alt-Tab`

Comment: If your intention is to prevent a user from alt+tabbing out for example then you can't and for good reason.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can like this

```
document.onkeydown = function (e) {
        alert('_..........._');
        return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can prevent the default action on the key down event listener.

```js
var output = document.querySelector('#output'),
    input = document.querySelector('#input');

// use the keypress keyCode as the key
var messages = {
  37: 'All right stop collaborate and listen',
  38: 'Ice is back with my brand new invention',
  39: 'Something grabs a hold of me tightly',
  40: 'Flow like a harpoon daily and nightly'
}

addEvent(window, 'keydown', function( e ){
  e.preventDefault();
  var msg;
  if( messages[ e.keyCode ] != null ) {
     msg = messages[ e.keyCode ];
  }
  else {
     msg = "can't touch dis: " + String.fromCharCode( e.keyCode ) + ' ' + e.keyCode;
  }
  
  log( msg );
});

// cross brrowser events
function addEvent( el, evt, fn, capture ){
  if( el.addEventListener ){
    el.addEventListener( evt, fn, capture )  
  } 
  else if( el.attachEvent ){
    el.attachEvent('on' + evt, fn );
  } 
  else {
    el['on' + evt] = fn; 
  }  
}

function log( msg ){
  output.innerHTML = msg + '\n' + output.innerHTML;
}
```

```html
<h3>you can't type anywhere in this window</h3>
<textarea id="input"></textarea>
<pre id="output"></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be a solution:

```js
window.onkeydown = () => {
  showMessage();
  return false;
}
window.onkeypress = () => {
  return false;
}
window.onkeyup = () => {
  return false;
}

function showMessage() {
  alert(";)");
}
```

```html
<b>Try pressing any key!</b>
<br>
<br>
<textarea placeholder="Try typing something..."></textarea>
```